# What role does glycerin or sugar play in bubble formula?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

From: http://bubbleblowers.com/homemade.html

> Exploratorium Bubble Formula
>   from the Exploratorium web site
>   2/3 cup Joy dishwashing soap
>   1 gallon water
>   ***2 to 3 tablespoons of glycerin*** (available in pharmacies or chemical supply houses)
>
> Cyndi's Bubble Recipes from the Nathan's Wish web site 1/2 cup of
>   dishwashing liquid (Dawn or Joy) 2 cups of water ***2 teaspoons of sugar***

What role does glycerin or sugar play in bubble formula?  ***Are sugar or glycerin better than each other in some way w.r.t this formula?***

Answer (score 1):

From: [image]

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-best-bubbles/

> The solution with only water and detergent probably made smaller,
>   shorter-lived bubbles compared to the solutions with glycerin or corn
>   syrup. Bubbles burst when the layer of water molecules between the
>   detergent molecules evaporates. But Glycerin and corn syrup form weak
>   bonds with the water molecules and slow down the evaporation process,
>   thus improving the life span and durability of the bubble. Glycerin
>   makes stronger, longer-lasting bubbles, but corn syrup is often
>   substituted in bubble solutions because it is cheaper. Can you find
>   other substances around the house that can be added to water to make a
>   bubble solution? If you try products such as shampoo or liquid hand
>   soap, you can check their ingredients to see what might be helping to
>   make the bubbles form.